# Scanf() behaving odd for specific case

Tags: c, scanf, equality

I've got some C code that accepts simple equations **(with no spaces)** in 6 different formats.

```
x + int = int
x - int = int
int + x = int
int - x = int
int + int = x
int - int = x
```

I'm using scanf to extract the numbers in the equations, which works for the first 4 cases, but doesn't for the last 2. And I have no idea why.

For example. For the first 2 formats I'm using this:

```
int digit1, digit2;
char operand;
if(scanf("x%c%d=%d", &operand, &digit1, &digit2) == 3) {
    if(operand == '+') {
        printf("x=%d", (digit2-digit1));
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("x=%d", (digit2+digit1));
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And this works.

For the last two formats I'm using this (very similar) code:

```
int digit1, digit2;
char operand;
if(scanf("%d%c%d=x", &digit1, &operand, &digit2) == 3) {
    if(operand == '+') {
        printf("x=%d", (digit1+digit2));
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("x=%d", (digit1-digit2));
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work as expected for some reason.

I tried some different things and I found that scanf() skips the first digit and the math operator. This results in the if statement not being true because now scanf() only returns 2, because it sets digit1 to the second digit, operand to the '=' sign and then cannot find anymore digits.

My question is why is scanf() not "seeing" the first digit.

For this example input

```
10+12=x
```

Current behaviour:

```
digit1 = 12
operand = '='
digit2 = 0
```

Desired behaviour:

```
digit1 = 10
operand = '+'
digit2 = 12
```

Comment: Pls complete code - with variable declarations

Comment: Your code is correct for each case. Check how you combine them.

Comment: small observation. You say *operand*, what you mean is *operator*

Comment: I just tried this and it works for me. Could you please the output of running your program end-to-end ?

Comment: Each time an equation is entered and calculated the program terminates when it is done.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The `%c` conversion specification doesn't skip leading spaces; `%d` and most others (all except `%[…]` scan sets and `%n`) do skip leading spaces.  You should add a suitable sprinkling of spaces in the formats to allow corresponding zero-or-more spaces in the input.  Do NOT use trailing white space in a `scanf()` format.  And your `12+13` shows

Comment: I think you'd do better reading lines of characters ([`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then use `sscanf()` (possibly in several attempts) to parse the strings.  This allows you to print the input lines, and report the errors more coherently — and often makes life easier for line-based input.

Answer (score 0):

My code was broken because of the code I had for the 3rd and 4th case.

I fixed it by combining the code for case 3 4 5 and 6.

```
if(scanf("%d%c", &digit1, &operator) == 2) {
    if(scanf("%d=x", &digit2) == 1) {
        if(operator == '+') {
            printf("x=%d", (digit1+digit2));
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("x=%d", (digit1-digit2));
            exit(0);
        }
    } else if(scanf("x=%d", &digit2) == 1) {
        if(operator == '+') {
            printf("x=%d", (digit2-digit1));
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("x=%d", (digit1-digit2));
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```